# Delete and Truncate

Tags: sql

Delete can continue identity values?
how Truncate affects identity values?

Comment: `truncate table` resets identity values.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

TRUNCATE always removes all the rows from a table, leaving the table empty and the table structure intact whereas DELETE may remove conditionally if the where clause is used. The rows deleted by TRUNCATE TABLE statement cannot be restored and you can not specify the where clause in the TRUNCATE statement

Comment: So is there any way you can find the data back after you delete it? YOu cannot trace it back after you truncate it, can you?